# Why schedule processes?

Tags: operating-system

I am trying to understand the following reasons of why we must schedule processes:

```
❖ Bursts of CPU usage alternate with periods of I/O wait
❖ Some processes are CPU-bound: they don’t make many I/O requests
❖ Other processes are I/O-bound and make many kernel requests
```

I am little confused about the terminology being used in this case. They refer to bursts of CPU usage in periods of I/O wait. What does that mean?. Does that mean when some set of instructions is being executed and these are blocked by an unexpected I/O resource, somehow these instructions remain idle in the CPU?.

Comment: I think you need to expand your quote a bit more to figure out what is going on.

Comment: The OS kernel is written to manage resources, one of which is execution on a core.  If an executing thread makes a request for another resource that is currently unavailable, (eg. for network data that has not yet arrived, or KB input when you haven't presssed any key, or a signal from another thread), then further execution of that thread is stopped until that resource becomes available.  You need to read up more - SO is not a teaching site.